# Where can twitter boostrap version 1.4 examples and documentation be found?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Boostrap has been recently upgraded to version 2. Project description with examples available at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ is now replaced with information about how to use version 2.

Does anyone know if pages describing older version - 1.4 - can still be found anywhere?

Comment: The answer is in the first google hit for: bootstrp 1.4 doc

Comment: http://bootstrapdocs.com/ - all the versions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue on this in the github bootstrap issue tracker: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1630 .

The current status for this issue is still unresolved, since there is still no official online vieweable 1.4 doc available. But it does contain a link to downloadable versions of the documentation: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tags . The direct link to the 1.4 documentation is: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tarball/v1.4.0 .

Comment: Awesome - thanks! For future reference, there's pdf with 1.4 documentation: http://blog.actblue.com/files/bootstrap-1.4-docs.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This is the 1.4 online viewable documentation:
http://twitter-bootstrap.node1.zygote.cc/

Hope it helps!